# Prove that $F$ can be uniformly approximated for functions of the form $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^n f_kg_k}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X,T$ compact metric spaces. Let $F:X\times T:\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a continuous function prove that $F$ can be uniformly aproximated for functions of the form $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^n f_kg_k}$  where $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and $g:T\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ are continuous functions

I'm trying to use Stone-Weierstrass Theorem for complex case, but i don't have a clear idea of how solve this exercise. can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $F$ is uniformly continuous on the compact space $X\times T$, choose some open covers $(A_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ and $(B_{j})_{j=1}^{m}$ for $X$ and $T$ respectively such that the oscillation of $f$ on $A_{i}\times B_{j}$ is small, say, less than $\epsilon>0$.

Then consider the partition of unity $(\varphi_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ and $(\psi_{j})_{j=1}^{m}$ of $(A_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ and $(B_{j})_{j=1}^{m}$ respectively. For each $1\leq i\leq n$ and $1\leq j\leq m$, pick an $a_{i,j}=f(t_{i},s_{j})$, $t_{i}\in A_{i}$, $s_{j}\in B_{j}$, then argue that $\displaystyle\sum_{1\leq i\leq n,1\leq j\leq m}a_{i,j}\varphi_{i}\psi_{j}$ approximates $f$ in the uniform norm.

The $f_{k}$ and $g_{k}$ are chosen to be suitable rearrangement of $a_{i,j}\varphi_{i}\psi_{j}$.

**Edit:**

The partition of unity is such that $\displaystyle\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}\varphi_{i}=1$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{1\leq j\leq m}\psi_{j}=1$ and hence 
\begin{align*}
f(s,t)=\sum_{1\leq i\leq n, 1\leq j\leq m}f(s,t)\varphi_{i}(s)\psi_{j}(t),
\end{align*} 
then
\begin{align*}
&\left|f(s,t)-\sum_{1\leq i\leq n,1\leq j\leq m}a_{i,j}\varphi_{i}\psi_{j}\right|\\
&\sum_{1\leq i\leq n, 1\leq j\leq m}|f(s,t)-a_{i,j}|\varphi_{i}(s)\varphi_{j}(t)\\
&<\epsilon\cdot\sum_{1\leq i\leq n, 1\leq j\leq m}\varphi_{i}(s)\varphi_{j}(t)\\
&=\epsilon.
\end{align*}

Comment: I dont see very clear why $\displaystyle\sum_{1\leq i\leq n,1\leq j\leq m}a_{i,j}\varphi_{i}\psi_{j}$ approximates $f$ can you be more specific?

Comment: You may look at the edited post now.

Comment: Ohhh looks great, $|f(s,t)-a_{i,j}| < \epsilon$ by hypothesis of continuity correct?

Comment: The oscillation on $A_{i}\times B_{j}$ is less than $\epsilon>0$, this can be done by uniform continuity of $f$.

Comment: Great. Thanks for all